# Perl : inheritance - base and child class

Tags: perl, inheritance, radix

Is it possible to import a base class having the same name as that of the package name in another location ?

```
package Foo;
use base 'Foo';
```

I have to use 'Foo' as the base class located in another location. Is it possible ?

Comment: You can reopen package outside of it and add to it (no inheritance required).

Comment: package names are globally unique in a Perl interpreter. You cannot have two different packages of the same name. Declaring a `package` that already exists just re-enters that existing context.

Answer (score 3):

No you can't do that. A base class is the place Perl looks for a method that isn't defined in the current package.

If you wrote things like this and Perl failed to find `Foo::method` then it would look in the base class `Foo::method` and so the search would be endless.